# What tools are available to tune chunk_length_kb?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

How should I know whether I need to tweak `chunk_length_kb` for table? What tools do I have at hand to find a better `chunk_length_kb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the least frequently tuned variables - the best way to tune it is based on benchmarking with your actual data (as different data will behave in different ways). The defaults are fairly sane, though - you may see a few percent improvement by moving either up or down, but it's unlikely to be major.